# -er vs -ing when characterizing someone

Tags: differences, suffixes, semantics

For example someone wants to use both their nationality and occupation in their nickname (e.g. serb and coder), what is a better choice:

- cod*ing* serb
- cod*er* serb

I understand basic semantic difference. For me coder is an occupation and coding is basically something you happen to do at the moment. I just want to know how it sounds for the natives. How would they perceive the semantics of both options?

Comment: *Serbian coder* would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems to me it wouldn't look good as a nickname on social media and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"coding serb" is confusing as a title (eg a nickname) because it has multiple meanings:  it could mean

a) "someone who is programming for the serb programming language" (this may or may not exist but the phrase can be parsed this way regardless) - like "coding javascript".

b) "a serb, ie someone from Serbia, who is coding at the moment", which i assume is the intended meaning.

"coder serb" could mean either

a) a serb, ie someone *from* Serbia, who describes themselves as "a coder"

b) someone *called* "serb" who describes themselves as "a coder"

So, both have some ambiguity, but i think the ambiguity is smaller for "coder serb", and most people would (I think) assume that "serb" referred to your nationality rather than your name.